# Как исправить код?

Tags: c++

Дан двумерный массив из 5 строк и 6 столбцов. Определить, для каждой нечетной строки минимальный элемент. Найти произведение этих элементов.

язык - С++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#pragma hdrstop

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma argsused
int main(int argc, char* argv[])  
{int a[5][6]={0},i,j;  
  float s=1;  
randomize();  
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)  
{  
for (j = 0; j < 6; j++)  
{
a[i][j]=random(100);  
printf("%4d",a[i][j]);  
if(i%2!=0)  
{
printf (" %d\n",a[i][j]); //тогда число нечетное  
}
if (a[i][j]>a[5][j]) a[5][j]=a[i][j];  
}
printf("  min=%d\n",a[i][6]);  s=s*a[5][j];}  
printf(" proizvedenie = %f",s);  
getchar();getchar();

    return 0;
```

минимальный элемент всегда выдает 0. и с произведением проблема

Answer (score 1):

Несколько советов.

1) Не жмотитьтся и для поиска минимума выделить отдельную переменную (int vmin;)

2) Зачем float для произведения двух (*из условия задачи*) целых, меньших 100 ???

3) По условию, Вам нужны нечетные строки. Так их и перебирайте (for(i = 1; i < 5; i+=2) {...)

4) Для получения исходных данных пишите a[i][j] = rand() % 100; Если хотите, чтобы от запуска к запуска данные былии разными в начале программы напишите srand(time(NULL));

5) Догадаться, как искать минимум, предоставляется Вам.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы найти минимальный элемент и т.д.: Для начала заполни весь массив, а потом работай с ним.